# Custom attribute if the field is null

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I want to create a custom attribute which returns my own text given as parameter if variable is null, if not, just return this variable. My problem is, I don't know how to call this variable.

My attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class IfNullAttribute : Attribute
{

    public IfNullAttribute()
    {
    }

}
```

My variable:

```
    public virtual Task ParentTask_Ref { get; set; }
```

Thanks for any response!

Comment: Your variable is a `Task`, is your default going to be a `Task<string>`?

Comment: Are you sure you understand what is `Attribute`?

Comment: Task is object created by EntityFramework

Comment: I want to create something like IsValid from ValidationAttribute which tells me when my variable is null